# How to resolve an InvalidCastException for two Objects of the same type in an ArcMap AddIn?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcmap, arcobjects, .net, add-in

I'm trying to work through an InvalidCastException that is being thrown when a form is displayed from an ArcMap Addin. This is a fairly recent occurrence and I haven't identified what has changed that would cause this exception.  The objects are System.Collections.Generic.List (although my gut is telling me that isn't relevant).

```
[A]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[XXX] cannot be cast to [B]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[XXX]. 
Type A originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. 
Type B originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
```

I believe this issue is closely related to this one: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500280/invalidcastexception-for-two-objects-of-the-same-type but complicated due to the fact that it is ArcMap that is loading the assemblies. I'm attempted to use the Assembly Binding Log Viewer, but so far, unsuccessful (nothing ArcMap related is being shown).  But I'm guessing ArcMap is loading the same assembly twice.

I've tried clearing my assembly cache and the ArcGIS AddIn folders, but had with no luck.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a sample project that you can share?

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to do that, although I did track it down the cause to a TypeLoadException of the item in the Generic.List, which was an Enum.  Resolved by using a list of the byte (enum data type) and casting during runtime.  I  still haven't identified the exact cause (enum does have custom attributes so it might be similar to the CodeAccessSecurityAttribute bug).  Not sure if I've got enough for an answer, but once I do...I'll pull together what I have.